# Is Fourier analysis applicable to lightwaves?

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, fourier-transform

I'm a mathematician with little understanding of physics.

My questions: In mathematics, we decompose a wave into its elementary parts by using the Fourier transform.

- Is this process applicable to lightwaves, ie. may we think of lightwaves as complicated functions arising from several elementary functions that overlay each other?
- Do the elementary functions correspond to single photons, or to groups of photons?
- Does a glass prism do the job of a Fourier transform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes. Not just a yes, a YES! Optics is one of the subjects that uses Fourier transforms all of the time. (Like a lot of other subjects in physics and engineering)

If we'll think about a  the light wave (or more precisely, the electric field) in one point in space we we'll see it varying with time. If it has a specific frequency $\omega$, meaning that the electric field will be $E=E_0 \cos (\omega t +\varphi ) $ we will see it as a specific color. For example, the light is called "red" when $\omega = 2.7\cdot 10^{15}$, "yellow" when $\omega = 3.25\cdot 10^{15} $ and "blue" when $\omega = 4.2\cdot 10^{15}$, etc...

If you mix these colors, each with a different initial phase and amplitude you can create any function you want*. White light for example is just an addition of a lot of cosines with a lot of different frequencies.

The discussion above was in a specific point in space, but now I want to talk about a specific temporal frequency. lets say you have a red laser, so by telling you its red, you know that in each point in space the wave will oscillate at a specific frequency. It can be shown that the spacial frequency (often written as $\vec{k}$) is responsible for the direction of propagation, and  by introducing spacial perturbations into the laser beam, it will split into different directions eventually. This phenomenon is called "diffraction" and when analyzing diffraction in the far field region, Fourier transforming the field (in space) will give you information how much energy will go in different directions.

A prism is a device that gives for each $\omega$ a different $\vec{k}$, meaning you can think of it as performing a Fourier transform and sending each color in a different direction. It should be noted that if you want to find the amplitude and phase of each frequency component experimentally by performing manipulations and detection at the other end of a prism (and in principal, the frequency spectrum is continuous so in that case it's impossible) it will be quite difficult.

footnote: Well, not any function, you can't create $E=e^{t^2}$ but that is not considered physical. As a mathematician you are likely aware of the limitations of the Fourier transform, but these limitations exists in the "real world" too so that's ok.

---

I think it should be emphasized that the answer to your second question is no. The elementary functions are cosines (as always in fourier transform) which correspond to colors (for transforming in time) and directions (for transforming in space). Photons are a totally different thing which are not connected at all to this subject.

Comment: It's too strong to say that photons aren't related "at all".  A photon is the excitation [unrelated] of an electromagnetic mode [related].  A mode is a spatial distribution of the field at a single frequency.  It has one frequency, but in general it has a distribution of $\vec{k}$ vectors.  The spatial distribution, say $X(\vec{r})$, can be Fourier analyzed to $\tilde{X}(\vec{k})$ .  Think of a cavity having conducting walls, or a laser beam.

Comment: I know that, but the fact that photons have the same properties of light waves isn't shocking, its part of their definition. Of course you need Fourier to describe them, like many other objects, but they aren't the fundamental functions he's talking about. So to avoid confusion I wanted to emphasized that they aren't the functions he looking for.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with any of the terms (I'm a physics dummie). It seems as though WP defines spatial frequency without direction, so that your definition measures oscillations *in a direction*. This would, in general, make it dependent of the point (except for your example of the laser, where it's the same everywhere within the beam, unless it's diffracted). I think I'm going to ask a follow-up question about how a prism really works. This should also be an instance of diffraction, right?

Comment: @AlgebraicsAnonymous It is very difficult to explain everything "on one foot". I suggest you watch the following videos:
1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuX_UExHa0M (until 47:10. This will help to get a bit of intuition about temporal periodic phenomenon and the meaning of amplitude and phase)
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hElGpHTo-80 (until 5:30. This will help you understand the definitions of $k$ and $\omega$ )

About the prism, before I explain: do you understand the concept of Green's function? (In differential equations)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, if you are given a certain domain inside a Euclidean space, the corresponding Green function is the function that delivers the solution to a linear PDE if one integrates against it in one variable. (In the terminology we used back then, the distribution defined by it would be called a fundamental solution.)

Comment: Oh, and regarding the videos @OfekGillon : I didn't have time to watch the first, but in the second, the definition given was the same as on Wikipedia. I do believe I understand it though (basically it seems to disregard speed). Note that I have asked a follow-up question about the prism, in case you wanna earn the points you deserve for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

A glass prism is not a Fourier Transformer, instead it is a gadget that moves the various frequency components to different spatial locations, it is more like an array of *almost* filters. Almost filters because to be a filter it also needs a rejection mechanism of frequencies not needed, for example an array of slits to remove the unneeded frequencies from the spread. To be a Fourier Transformer one also needs a coherent detector after each slit (ie., bandpass filter), where coherent means being able to detect amplitude *and* phase. If only amplitude is detected then you  get the "spectrum" compatible with the resolution here defined primarily by the slit width and the prism's spread.

Comment: I don't agree about the phase requirement. The ear (the cochlea) does a Fourier transform, an optical grating too, or a crystal in x-ray diffraction. It is just that without phase information it is difficult to do the inverse operation.

Comment: @pieter if the phase information is missing then a non-minimum phase function cannot be inverted from its amplitude distribution for the latter does not uniquely determine the former. In its conventional mathematical definition a power (amplitude) spectrum is not a Fourier Transform of the underlying time function.

Comment: @pieter the question (from a mathematician) was about *Fourier Transform* and I assume that he knows the difference between it and power spectral density, hence my answer.

Comment: Hello hyportnex, I was unaware of the term "power spectral density", but I see that it's very important that the prism "forgets" the phase, so that there will be many lightwave functions that yield the same spectrum if outputted through a prism, since the phase is to quick to be visible to the naked eye. Hence the upvote.

Comment: the human eye is a "power detector" and is completely insensitive to phase and so is the ear, they are both *noncoherent receivers* in the radar/comms engineer's usage of the word. It is not just that the phase variation is too quick to be detectable but that it is not detected because there is no reference to which it can be compared.